# Arithmetic Function counting products

Tags: number-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be the function such that $f(n)$ is the amount of numbers that is a product of two numbers between 1 and $n$. Prove that $f(n)=o(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by Erdős in 1960 (see "An asymptotic inequality in the theory of numbers", Vestnik Leningrad. Univ., 15, 
41-49 (in Russian)). Later Linnik and Vinogradov showed that $f(n)$ is $O(n^2/(\log n)^c)$ for some $c > 0$. For a proof see Theorem 23 at p. 33 in "Divisors" by Hall and Tenenbaum. More references can be found at this link: [OEIS'sequence A027424](https://oeis.org/A027424).